# How can I get html elements classes inside Angular Component?

Tags: angular

I am using ViewChild directive and get element reference.

How can I get html elements classes inside Angular Component ?

How can I get html elements custom classes (not the classes that create angular) inside Angular Component ?

[Link to demo example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with a few snippets of your code?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am already add some code snippets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking for just getting and settings classes from any HTML elements like div etc. you can use ElmentRef in angular.

You can use **template variable** (i.e. #useThisTemplateVar) to get HTML element and simply target that element with **@ViewChild()** decorator.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  template: `

 <div #useThisTemplateVar class="myClass">
   My some other content!
 </div>

<button type="button" (click)="changeClass()">change class</button>

`,
  styleUrls: ["./example.component.scss"]
})

export class ExampleComponent implements {

@ViewChild('useThisTemplateVar') elRef: ElementRef; 
changeClass(): void {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.className === "myClass" ? 
  this.elRef.nativeElement.className = "yourClass" : 
  this.elRef.nativeElement.className = "myClass"; 
}

}
```

**Note:** As per angular Security guide you should stop using direct access to DOM elements to prevent XSS attacks to your Web Application.

**Learn More:** [ElementRef Angular official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#description), [Angular security Guide](https://angular.io/guide/security)

Answer (score 2):

```
this.viewChild.nativeElement.classList
```

This way you can get your Class list as array.